# The 'Run PowerShell' artifact failed to install with CommandNotFoundException

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, artifact, azure-devtest-labs

I'm trying to download and run a PowerShell script (from blob storage) using the **Run Powershell** artifact on an existing VM in Azure DevTest labs.

I get the following error and I assume I am doing something stupid.

```
& : The term './script.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & ./script.ps1
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (./script.ps1:String) [], Comman 
   dNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Here is my setup...

[image: Image showing artifact setup with URL and script name matching]

I have also tried the JSON array syntax, which gave the same result, and an invalid URL which gave a 404 error so it seems as if it is downloading my script but then failing to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is info I wrote a while back. 
Few items to note:

- Folder structure is not supported as of this writing. Therefore, script needs to be at the root of the container
- Ensure your blob is public

---

First you will need your file in Azure storage. Once uploaded in your container, click the file to get to its properties and copy the URL field.

As an example, I have created the following Run.ps1 script file and uploaded it to storage as a blob:

```
param ( [string]$drive = "c:\" )
param ( [string]$folderName = "DefaultFolderName" )

New-Item -Path $drive -Name $folderName -ItemType "directory"
```

Now, while adding the 'Run PowerShell' artifact to the VM, we provide the following information:

**File URI(s):** URL field copied from earlier step. (eg. https://myblob.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/Run.ps1)

**Script to Run:** Name of the PS1 script, (eg. Run.ps1)

**Script Arguments:** Arguments as you would write them at the end of your command (eg. -drive "d:\" -folderName "MyFolder")

Comment: I saw this in my research before I posted. My script isn't even being run.    However, it does appear to be being downloaded.